# Impala Calculate Quantile From other Quantile

Tags: sql, impala

As an example suppose we have the table:

```
name | val
-----------
Alice| 1
Bob  | 2
```

I can get the quantiles of the above values by doing

```
SELECT *, NTILE(2) over (ORDER BY val ASC) AS quantile FROM table
```

which gives:

```
name | val | quantile |
-----------|----------|
Alice| 1   |     1
Bob  | 2   |     2
```

Suppose now I have a bigger table

```
name | val
-----------
Alice| 1
Bob  | 2
Joe  | 1.8
```

I would like to calculate the quantile for Joe **with respect to the previous quantile**. In other words my previous quantile does a split of "<1.5" and ">=1.5", so that I should see:

```
name | val | quantile |
-----------|----------|
Alice| 1   |    1     |
Bob  | 2   |    2     |
Joe  | 1.8 |    2     |
```

Is there an easy way of doing this with **Impala**, in a way that generalizes to NTILE(n) for arbitrary n? In theory, I could find the minimum and maximum values for each quantile level from the prior quantile (suppose for simplicity val is continuous), but this is very tedious.

Comment: what do you mean by *my previous quantile does a split of "<1.5" and ">=1.5*?

Comment: @vkp: So this is a bad example because I only have two vals but imagine I had a huge table of vals, which would then split into quantiles. Each quantile has a certain range of values to it. I want to calculate quantiles for the new vals by inferring which quantile they fall into from the prior quantiles.

Comment: where are the new vals coming from? are they not in the table already? do you want to store this calculated column in the table so when a new row is inserted it would automatically get a value?

Comment: What you really want is `PERCENTILE_CONT()` or `MEDIAN()`, but I don't think they are yet implemented.